# Jest test __DEV__ is not defined

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

Basically my issue is that I get an error message, "`__DEV__` is not defined" when I run jest. So I have read stackoverflow and other google posts on this. Some have suggested removing my .babelrc, but I actually need that file. Others have suggested adding

```
"globals": {
  "__DEV__": true
}
```

To my package.json. I did that as well. I even deleted my node modules folder and re-installed. What should I do? Odd thing is that it was working before, but not now.

Comment: FYI, I was getting this when importing a Component in `react-native` in my `globalSetup` file. Moving this setup from `globalSetup` to `setupFilesAfterEnv` did the trick, since the `jest` test environment is loaded before the files listed in `setupFilesAfterEnv` are run.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a jest.config.json file in the root of your react-native project and add this globally as such

```
{
"jest": {
    "globals": {
    "__DEV__": true
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `globals.DEV = true` to your test file or set it in `globals` part of your [jest settings](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#globals-object)

Comment: can you elaborate on which test file? like each and every one?

Comment: In each test file where you have to set `DEV` to true to test your source.

Comment: that's all my files. i tried to add it to each of them, but I still get this error. funny thing though, i think this happens when I do the line: import 'react-native';

Comment: turns out I only get that error when I run jest inside the js directory. the js directory is inside the root directory. I did this because originally when I ran jest in the root directory I got this error "Path must be a string. Received [ '/Users/someone/app' ]". However if I ran npm test on the root directory, it knows to find jest and it runs fine. Why is that though?

Answer (score 1):

I got this when I was running Detox E2E tests inside of my react native app. Then use to work just fine but then I upgraded my mac OS and xcode and they started throwing Reference error **DEV** is not defined. Not sure why it was fine before and then broke after that.

My issue was fixed when I removed any code that was being imported from my react native app inside of the detox E2E tests. So the issue was importing any javascript from my app/ folder. I had a simple utility log function that wraps console.log which was the culprit. I did not need to modify any jest configs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue I updated my jest by running in the terminal `npm update jest` this solved the issue for me.